# ViewModel vs Activity member variable?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

Going by this image, the lifecycle of a ViewModel is pretty much like that of an Activity instance, so why not just use an activity instance variable?  Is a ViewModel better because of the automatic call to `onClear`? Or because it is observable (in which case why not just have observable, normal member variables)? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the graphic is not clear enough but the printed lifecycle hooks are from the activity, the viewmodel remains the same until the activity is completely finished.

So, a variable in the activity instance would be released after rotation for example as that activity instance is going to be destroyed while a new activity instance is created. But this would not happen if it's on the ViewModel as both would use the same one.

Comment: why would the variable be released if the instance is still live?  In a Java object, instance variables are available until garbage collection.

Comment: or maybe the graphic implies that after `onDestroy` a new instance is created for the `onCreate` call?  How does Android/Jetpack know which new instance to transfer the member variable to? (thoroughly confused because the instantiation is not clear; sorry)

Comment: Because that activity is not alive anymore, a new instance of that activity is going to be created at that same moment but it's not the same instance. But they will share the same ViewModel. That's why an onDestroy and onCreate are in that graphic, they are from the same activity but not the same instance.

Comment: that a new instance would share the same ViewModel is critical -- if you could highlight that in your answer it would help a lot; and even better how does the library manage to do this if one looks at it from a pure Java/Kotlin perspective